# omxplayer playlist without black between videos at 1920x1080

Tags: video, raspberry-pi

I'm reading lot of posts/people using Raspberry and omxplayer (with some Python or script helper program) to allow playlist management without gaps between files (launching one file and pausing it, and then launching a second file and unpause first just when second one reaches the end).

This is great, but in my case it doesn't work at 1080p resolution (even with gpu mem at 320MB). Only work for 720p.

Has anyone been able to make it work with 1080p videos?